# Trying to use .after to loop the result of a function in a tkinter Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

New to Python and I would need some help please.
I am trying to make a simple GUI that at the moment shows CPU and Memory in 2 Labels, I managed to get the results showing but I want them to refresh automatically in the GUI. I tried .after method but I guess I am doing something wrong as I see the GUI for left label showing the result, but is not refreshing and also the GUI it's a bit laggy. So I feel that something is happening but not what I want. I am currently only trying to get refreshed cpu_percent() on the left_label . As I will be able to change after the others when I find out how. :)

Working code below without the refresh part. Thank you in advance !

```
import tkinter
import psutil


main_window = tkinter.Tk()
main_window.title("GUI")


def cpu_percent():
    cpu_percent_var = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    main_window.after(1000, cpu_percent)
    return cpu_percent_var


def virtual_memory_percent():
    virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
    total, available, percent, used, free = virtual_memory
    memory_percent = percent
    return memory_percent
    # print("Memory used is {} GB".format(round(used/1073741824, 2)))     # 1 GB = 1073741824 bytes


cpu_monitor_percent = cpu_percent()
print(str(cpu_monitor_percent))
memory_monitor_percent = "Memory at " + str(virtual_memory_percent()) + "%"
print(memory_monitor_percent)


main_window.columnconfigure(0)
main_window.rowconfigure(0)

main_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window, padx=3, pady=3)
main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwes")

left_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_frame, borderwidth=3, relief="raised")
left_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
left_label = tkinter.Label(left_frame, text=cpu_monitor_percent)
left_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=12, pady=12)

right_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_frame, borderwidth=3, relief="raised")
right_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)
right_label = tkinter.Label(right_frame, text=memory_monitor_percent)
right_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=12, pady=12)

main_window.after(1000, cpu_percent)
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ask yourself when you define `main_window` and when you call `main_window.after(...)`. It's not happening in the order you seem to think it is happening.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley ! Thanks for that. I managed to get rid of the NameError. The problem is that I still can't make the .after method refresh the result of the function. I realized that I have another issue so I changed some things, like a different var name for  cpu_percent as it was the same as the function, and also I left cpu_monitor_percent = cpu_percent() instea of = to "CPU usage at " + str(cpu_percent()) + "%" . I edited the code above and the GUI shows the number but still does not refresh it, but it is laggy so I guess that something is happening. Don't know what I am missing though :(